# how to debug PHP script in bash

Tags: bash, php

Can someone tell me the best way to run a PHP script and output content and errors to a text file (using nohup) using the unix shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/php script.php > script.out 2>&1
```

I don't know why you'd want to use nohup but that would be

```
nohup /usr/bin/php script.php > script.out 2>&1 &
```

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php)